# Importar múltiples líneas de un archivo .csv a una base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, app

Me han pedido que haga lo siguiente: En un archivo csv hay 5 líneas, cada una con una serie de datos,la primera línea va en la tabla de preguntas y las otras 4 en la tabla de repuestas. Soy principiante en PHP y no me aclaro mucho, lo he intentado pero solo consigo que mi código importe todos los datos a las dos tablas. Es posible hacer lo que se me pide?

P.D: un amigo me ha dicho que tengo que hacer un parse y luego el mysql, pero no sé como hacerlo.

Ejemplo del .csv:

¿De qué color es el caballo blanco de Santiago 2?,¿De que color yet\'l caballu blancu de Santiago 2?,1,1,noimg,novideo (esto está en una sola línea)

respuesta_blanco,respuesta_blancu,1

respuesta_verde,respuesta_asturiano,0

respuesta_azul,respuesta_asturiano,0

respuesta_amarillo,respuesta_asturiano,0

Mi script PHP:

```html
<?php
 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '-';
$db_pass = '-';
 
$database = '-';
if (!@mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass))
    die("No se pudo establecer conexión a la base de datos");
 
if (!@mysql_select_db($database))
    die("base de datos no existe");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'Cargando nombre del archivo: '.$fname.' <br>';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);
 
         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
         {
             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
 
             while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                $sql1 = "INSERT into preguntas(pregunta, pregunta_asturiano, juego, dificultad, url_imagen, url_video) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";
                $sql2 = "INSERT into respuestas(respuesta, respuesta_asturiano, correcta) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
                mysql_query($sql1) and mysql_query($sql2) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
             }
             fclose($handle);
             echo "Importación exitosa!";
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Archivo invalido!";
         }
    }
 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que hacer una primera importación con los datos de la primera línea a la tabla preguntas y el resto de líneas a la de respuestas:

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
$sql1 = "INSERT into preguntas(pregunta, pregunta_asturiano, juego, dificultad, url_imagen, url_video) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";
mysql_query($sql1) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $sql2 = "INSERT into respuestas(respuesta, respuesta_asturiano, correcta) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
    mysql_query($sql2) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
}
```